# socket.emit is unavailable after adding adding state

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-redux

I am using socket.io to add test orders to the state when the button is clicked on. Everything works fine when i click the button once. After i click it the second time it says socket.emit is unavailable? This only happend   when i added the mapStateToProps. Before i was able to click on the button multiple times without any issues. Only after i added the mapState to props all of sudden the socket.emit function is unavailable. I am  not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client/build/index";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addNewOrder} from '../service/actions';


function ListOrders ({addNewOrder}) {

  let socket ;


   useEffect(()=> {
      socket = io("http://localhost:3001");

       socket.on("add_new_order", new_order => {

           // console.log(new_order);

           console.log("called once");

           addNewOrder(new_order);


       });





   },[]);


    function SendSocketData(socket) {


        /*
        *
        * Emit is all of a sudden undefined when click on the "Send Data" button second time
        *
        * */
        socket.emit("new_order", new_order => {

        });


    }



   return (



       <div className="App">
          <button onClick={()=>SendSocketData(socket)}>Send Data </button>
       </div>
   );


}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({

    orders: state.orders


})


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

    return ({

        addNewOrder: (order) => dispatch(addNewOrder(order))


    })




}
/*
*
*
* NOT WORKING WHEN I ADD mapStateToProps
*
* */
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ListOrders)
```

Comment: I put the let socket outside the ListOrders function and it worked... not sure why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the handler when component unmounts or addNewOrder changes:

```
//create socket on mount
const socket = useMemo(
  () => io('http://localhost:3001'),
  []
);
//create handler when addNewOrder changes
const handler = useCallback(
  (new_order) => {
    console.log('called once');
    addNewOrder(new_order);
  },
  [addNewOrder]
);
useEffect(() => {
  //add event listener when socket changes
  //  or when addNewOrder changes
  socket.on('add_new_order', handler);
  // return cleanup function to remove the event listener
  return () => socket.off('add_new_order', handler);
}, [socket, handler]);
```